# Trying to understand Grobner basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, groebner-basis

While studying Grobner basis, I realized that creating a basis from a given set of polynomials is not that hard, it is reduced to solving with Gauss Jordan a system of equations. What I don't understand is how to use them for other purposes. I have two examples here that I don't understand how to solve:

1. Find an ideal in Q[x, y] whose reduced Grobner basis (in lexicographic
   order) has cardinality 5 and there are precisely 19 standard monomials.
2. Using Grobner bases, find the minimal polynomials of $\sqrt[5]{6} + \sqrt[7]{8}$ and $\sqrt[5]{6} - \sqrt[7]{8}$.

How can I find the minimal polynomial using Grobner bases if I don't know for what polynomials to take the bases?

Comment: In [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/) `R=QQ[x_1,x_2,y,MonomialOrder=> Eliminate 2]`
`I=ideal(x_1^5-6,x_2^7-8,y-(x_1+x_2))`
`gens gb I`
`tex oo`

$y^{35}-42\,y^{30}-40\,y^{28}+756\,y^{25}-109200\,y^{23}+640\,y^{21}-7560\,y^{20}-6904800\,y^{
      18}-3816960\,y^{16}+45360\,y^{15}-5120\,y^{14}-68040000\,y^{13}+178295040\,y^{11}-163296\,y^{
      10}-13762560\,y^{9}-125193600\,y^{8}+20480\,y^{7}-284981760\,y^{6}+326592\,y^{5}-55480320\,y^{
      4}-26127360\,y^{3}-2580480\,y^{2}+2903040\,y-312704$

`J=ideal(x_1^5-6,x_2^7-8,y-(x_1-x_2))`
`gens gb J`

Comment: Thank you!. So, the only way of computing this is using a software?

Comment: You can compute the minimal polynomials by hand, but why would you want to avoid a CAS (software)? For your title (to understand Gröbner bases), use a smaller example!

Comment: It is mostly useful to know how an algorithm works. A good description of the famous Buchberger algorithm can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland In general one may need to select an irreducible factor of the result. For example, let $f(x)=x^4+12x+8$ with roots $r_1$, $r_2$, $r_3$, and $r_4$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Then $r_1+r_2$, $r_1+r_3$, and $r_1+r_4$ are all roots of $y^6-48y-64$. However,
`R=QQ[x_1,x_2,y,MonomialOrder=> Eliminate 2]`
`J=ideal(x_1^4+8*x_1+12, x_2^4+8*x_2+12, y-(x_1+x_2))`
`factor (flatten entries gens gb J)#0` yields `(y^4+64*y+192)(y^6-48*y-64)`